# Graphql: "message": "ID cannot represent value: 5a72240cf31713598588b70f"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I use `moongose` for work with `mongodb` on `nodejs` based app. Currently, I try to implement `Grapqhl` based API.

My query `graphql` schema looks like:

```
const schema = buildSchema(`                                                 
    type Query {                                                            
      predictionModels(active: Boolean): [PredictionModel]
    },                                                                                   
    type PredictionModel {                                                                                                 
        _id: ID                                                                                                             
        title: String
        active: Boolean                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                      
`)
```

but when I use:

```
query {
  predictionModels(active: true){
    _id
  }
}
```

As the response I get:

```
"errors": [
    {
      "message": "ID cannot represent value: 5a72240cf31713598588b70f",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "predictionModels",
        0,
        "_id"
      ]
    } ....
```

Prediction model mongoose schema:

```
const predictionModelSchema = new Schema({                                                                              
    title: { type: String, require: true, unique: true },                                                               
    modelId: { type: String, require: true, unique: true },                                                             
    description: { type: String, unique: true },                                                                        
    language: {type: String, enum: [ProgrammingLanguage.JS, ProgrammingLanguage.R], require: true},                     
    estimates: [{ type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'PredictionModelEstimate'}],                                                                                             
    method: { type: methodType, require: true},                                                                         
    active: { type: Boolean, require: true}                                                                             
})
```

Comment: This message shows up if the value provided for `_id` is neither a string nor an integer. Mongoose object id fields should be properly serialised by graphql-js by [this function](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/type/scalars.js#L120). Can you add your mongoose model?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a type issue, you could use:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
_id: new ObjectId(ID)
```